# add_host: with groups does not work on AAP

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-awx

I have a loop which constructs in-memory targets based on list of databases found on server.
These targets are assigned into different groups. The whole playbook works fine when executed from command line, but it "fails" when executed in Ansible Automation Platform (ansible 2.13.10).

This file is executed in a loop to add dynamic targets based databases detected.

UPDATED:

```
******************************************************
main.yml
tasks:
# detect all database installations on target host
# variable sid_list will be used inside add_db_targets.yml
- oracle_oratab:
    running_only: true
  register: sid_list
  tags: [always]

- debug:
    var: sid_list
  tags: [always]

# See notes in add_db_targets.yml
- include_tasks: add_db_targets.yml
  loop: "{{ ansible_play_hosts | sort() }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: outer_item
  run_once: yes
  tags: [always]
*******************************************************
add_db_targets.yml:
- name: Add crs/has for host {{ outer_item }}
  add_host:
    groups:
      - "{{ 'oraclecrs' if hostvars[outer_item]['sid_list']['oracle_homes'][ hostvars[outer_item]['sid_list']['oracle_list'][item].ORACLE_HOME ].home_ty\
pe == 'crs' else 'oracledatabase' }}"
    name: "{{ outer_item }}_{{ item }}"
    hostname: "{{ outer_item }}"

    ansible_connection: ssh
    ansible_ssh_user: "{{ ansible_ssh_user }}"
    ansible_port: "{{ ansible_port }}"
    #ansible_ssh_private_key_file: "{{ ansible_ssh_private_key_file }}"
    ansible_host: "{{ hostvars[outer_item]['ansible_host'] }}"

    ORACLE_BASE:  "{{ hostvars[outer_item]['sid_list']['oracle_list'][item].ORACLE_BASE }}"
    ORACLE_HOME:  "{{ hostvars[outer_item]['sid_list']['oracle_list'][item].ORACLE_HOME }}"
    ORACLE_SID:   "{{ hostvars[outer_item]['sid_list']['oracle_list'][item].ORACLE_SID }}"
    oracle_owner: "{{ hostvars[outer_item]['sid_list']['oracle_list'][item].owner }}"
  delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
  changed_when: False
  loop: "{{ hostvars[outer_item]['sid_list']['oracle_list'].keys() | sort }}"
  tags: [always]
```

The long condition adds a target into group either `oraclecrs` or `oracledatabase`.
Following playbooks are applied onto either these dynamically added targets:

```
# Segment 3. CRS/HAS Management.
- name: Oracle CRS/HAS Management
  hosts:
    - oraclecrs
  roles:
    - role: upgrade_crs

# Segment 4. DB home Management.
- name: Oracle DB Management
  hosts:
    - oracledatabase
  roles:
    - role: upgrade_database
```

This approach works for me when executed from command line, it even works from Execution environment podman image.
When executed in AAP the playbook ends with:

```
TASK [Add crs/has for host dbhost] ******************************
task path: /runner/project/Oracle12cto19c/add_db_targets.yml:30
creating host via 'add_host': hostname=dbhost_+ASM
creating host via 'add_host': hostname=dbhost_IVANDB01
ok: [dbhost -> 127.0.0.1] => (item=+ASM) => {
    "add_host": {
        "groups": [
            "oracle",
            "oraclecrs"
        ],
        "host_name": "dbhost_+ASM",
        "host_vars": {
            "ORACLE_BASE": "/opt/oracle/grid",
            "ORACLE_HOME": "/opt/oracle/grid/product/19.21.0.0",
            "ORACLE_SID": "+ASM",
            "ansible_connection": "ssh",
            "ansible_host": "dbhost",
        }
    },
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "item": "+ASM"
}
ok: [dbhost -> 127.0.0.1] => (item=IVANDB01) => {
    "add_host": {
        "groups": [
            "oracle",
            "oracledatabase"
        ],
        "host_name": "dbhost_IVANDB01",
        "host_vars": {
            "ORACLE_BASE": "/opt/oracle/ormerck",
            "ORACLE_HOME": "/opt/oracle/ormerck/product/19.21.0.0/db1",
            "ORACLE_SID": "IVANDB01",
            "ansible_connection": "ssh",
            "ansible_host": "dbhost",
        }
    },
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "item": "IVANDB01"
}
META: ran handlers
META: ran handlers

PLAY [Oracle CRS/HAS Management] ***********************************************
skipping: no hosts matched

PLAY [Oracle DB Management] ****************************************************
skipping: no hosts matched
```

I looks like in-memory targets are added, but their groups are somehow ignored, and no hosts are matched.

UPDATE: full example is here: https://github.com/ibre5041/ansible_oracle_modules_example/blob/main/oracle_oratab.yml

Comment: Could you add the part of your playbook where the `main.yml` gets invoked? Also, could you `debug` your `groups` variable right after your `include_tasks: add_db_targets.yml` task?

Comment: @AlexanderPletnev I've updated the example and added link to the whole project on GH.

Comment: thanks for update, but that's not exactly what I meant. Perhaps I should have been more specific. What I wanted to understand is what is the content of `groups` magic variable after adding the hosts and before running the next play. Maybe AAP somehow suppresses the dynamic changes of the inventory?

Comment: @AlexanderPletnev The whole idea works like this: 1st part of the playbook detects databases `A` and `B` on the targets and also clustered database `C`. It adds new dynamic targets `dbhost_A`, `dbhost_B` and `dbhost_C`. These targets have the same ssh connection parameters, plus some more host variables, and are assigned into host groups `oracledatabase` or `oraclecrs`. The rest of the playbook is applicable only onto these dynamically added targets.

Comment: I totally get the idea, I just wanted to see what AAP sees. It should definitely work (and you confirmed that it does without AAP). So it would be interesting to see what's in `groups` in the next play as well (you can add a dummy play running on `localhost` or `all` to output it).

Comment: I do not understand how this is possible. I created my own execution environment, which is a podman container. When I execute the same playbook manually from that container it works. I have mine own ansible installation inside that container. AAP has to execute mine playbook using some strange combination of parameters.

Comment: Thanks for hint, I will try to display values of variables `groups` and `group_names`.

Comment: @AlexanderPletnev so I have an explanation. On AAP I had been executing playbook with bigger inventory and also with `--limit` parameter. And as documentation states: `add_host: The hosts added will not bypass the --limit from the command line, so both of those need to be in agreement to make them available as play targets. They are still available from hostvars and for delegation as a normal part of the inventory.`

Comment: Cool! I think it's worth to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Explanation:

On AAP I had been executing playbook with bigger inventory and also with `--limit` parameter.

And as documentation states:

> add_host: The hosts added will not bypass the --limit from the command
> line, so both of those need to be in agreement to make them available
> as play targets. They are still available from hostvars and for
> delegation as a normal part of the inventory.

In mine case I had been adding targets dynamically having names like: `dbhost_A`, `db_host_B`, ...etc.

The solution is to use wildcard for limit when you also use `add_host`. For example:

```
ansible-playbook main.yml -i inventory.yml --limit dbhost*
```

This wildcard limit will allow matching dynamically added targets.